# NextJS i18n - Locale getting undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to migrate my website to NextJS, and I'm having trouble to do some internationalization.

I'm following the tutorial from [Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) itself, but my locale in the inspector is coming up as *undefined*.

What i'm doing wrong?
I'm using the latest version of nextJS.

Im trying to get some info from console.log.

```
console.log("Locale: " + locale);
console.log(router);
```

and it prints:
[image]

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en-US', 'pt-BR'],
        defaultLocale: 'pt-BR',
    },
}
```

**/pages/index.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import pt from '../locale/index/pt'
import en from '../locale/index/en'

export default function Home() {

    const router = useRouter();
    const { locale } = router;
    const t = locale === 'pt' ? pt : en;

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Head>
                <title>{t.title}</title>
            </Head>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**/locale/pt.js**

```
export default {
    title: "Teste Portugues."
}
```

**/locale/en.js**

```
export default {
    title: "Test English"
}
```

Some random info:
NextJS Version: 12.0.4
Chrome Version: 96.0.4664.55
Node Version: 17.0.1

Comment: Shouldn't `locale === 'pt'` be `locale === 'pt-BR'`?

Comment: Also you can `const locale = router.locale`

Comment: Is that the only thing you have in your `next.config.js`? Did you restart the dev server after making the changes to the config file?

Comment: @thegman1001 i've tried pt-BR too. Nothing happens

Comment: @illiachill ill try

Comment: @juliomalves yea, i've tried this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I did a restart of my computer, and after this, 3 days later, when i use console.log({locale}), it get my pt-BR locale normally.

(And i did nothing more)

So, i'll close the thread. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I got something similar and it was resolved by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in older versions of Next.js. yesterday, I had a similar issue, and after upgrading Next, React, and React-dom to their latest version, it worked like charm!.

Comment: i'm using the lastest version! I've installed three or four days ago

Comment: My bad I didn't notice that.

Comment: Did try to leverage `getStaticPaths` and see if it's undefined on the server-side as well ?. Because the configured locales are provided in the context parameter of the function under locales.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the server. If the next.config.js file is modified, you have to restart your server for the changes to take effect