# nextJs 13 i18n website is keep redirecting to the locale page, even if i deleted it

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13

I tried to used the page [localisation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization) for nextJs while I am using the app, this got me confused while working on it, and it resulted to having the app lags on the i18n route and got stuck on it, even if I restart the dev or use other nextJs applications.

I tried to restart the Dev, use another code editor, google the issue (no luck), hard reload with cache removing (CTRL+SHIFT+R) and removed the locale files and config.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days, the issue was solved by itself. The things that I tried:

- delete cache
- delete cookies
- restart pc

Not sure what were the issue,yet it's similar to this:

[NextJS i18n - Locale getting undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70191055/nextjs-i18n-locale-getting-undefined)